# Error al instalar MySql en Centos 7 (Paquete: (mysql80-community) Necesita: libcrypto.so.1.1)

Tags: mysql, mysqli, centos, centos7

Hola que tal tengo el siguiente error y lo extraño que la las libs ya esta instaladas estuve buscando por todos lados y no he encontrado una solución

```
Error: Paquete: mysql-community-client-8.0.18-1.el8.x86_64 (mysql80-community)
           Necesita: libcrypto.so.1.1()(64bit)
Error: Paquete: mysql-community-libs-8.0.18-1.el8.x86_64 (mysql80-community)
           Necesita: libssl.so.1.1()(64bit)
Error: Paquete: mysql-community-libs-8.0.18-1.el8.x86_64 (mysql80-community)
           Necesita: libssl.so.1.1(OPENSSL_1_1_1)(64bit)
Error: Paquete: mysql-community-server-8.0.18-1.el8.x86_64 (mysql80-community)
           Necesita: libstdc++.so.6(GLIBCXX_3.4.20)(64bit)
Error: Paquete: mysql-community-client-8.0.18-1.el8.x86_64 (mysql80-community)
           Necesita: libstdc++.so.6(GLIBCXX_3.4.21)(64bit)
Error: Paquete: mysql-community-server-8.0.18-1.el8.x86_64 (mysql80-community)
           Necesita: libssl.so.1.1(OPENSSL_1_1_0)(64bit)
Error: Paquete: mysql-community-server-8.0.18-1.el8.x86_64 (mysql80-community)
           Necesita: libcrypto.so.1.1(OPENSSL_1_1_0)(64bit)
Error: Paquete: mysql-community-server-8.0.18-1.el8.x86_64 (mysql80-community)
           Necesita: libcrypto.so.1.1()(64bit)
Error: Paquete: mysql-community-server-8.0.18-1.el8.x86_64 (mysql80-community)
           Necesita: libstdc++.so.6(CXXABI_1.3.11)(64bit)
Error: Paquete: mysql-community-client-8.0.18-1.el8.x86_64 (mysql80-community)
           Necesita: libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.28)(64bit)
Error: Paquete: mysql-community-client-8.0.18-1.el8.x86_64 (mysql80-community)
           Necesita: libcrypto.so.1.1(OPENSSL_1_1_0)(64bit)
Error: Paquete: mysql-community-libs-8.0.18-1.el8.x86_64 (mysql80-community)
           Necesita: libstdc++.so.6(GLIBCXX_3.4.21)(64bit)
Error: Paquete: mysql-community-client-8.0.18-1.el8.x86_64 (mysql80-community)
           Necesita: libtinfo.so.6()(64bit)
Error: Paquete: mysql-community-server-8.0.18-1.el8.x86_64 (mysql80-community)
           Necesita: libstdc++.so.6(GLIBCXX_3.4.21)(64bit)
Error: Paquete: 2:postfix-2.10.1-7.el7.x86_64 (@base)
           Necesita: libmysqlclient.so.18(libmysqlclient_18)(64bit)
           Eliminando: 1:mariadb-libs-5.5.64-1.el7.x86_64 (@base)
               libmysqlclient.so.18(libmysqlclient_18)(64bit)
           Obsoleto por: mysql-community-libs-8.0.18-1.el8.x86_64 (mysql80-community)
               No encontrado
Error: Paquete: mysql-community-server-8.0.18-1.el8.x86_64 (mysql80-community)
           Necesita: libssl.so.1.1(OPENSSL_1_1_1)(64bit)
Error: Paquete: mysql-community-libs-8.0.18-1.el8.x86_64 (mysql80-community)
           Necesita: libssl.so.1.1(OPENSSL_1_1_0)(64bit)
Error: Paquete: mysql-community-client-8.0.18-1.el8.x86_64 (mysql80-community)
           Necesita: libssl.so.1.1(OPENSSL_1_1_0)(64bit)
Error: Paquete: mysql-community-server-8.0.18-1.el8.x86_64 (mysql80-community)
           Necesita: libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.28)(64bit)
Error: Paquete: mysql-community-server-8.0.18-1.el8.x86_64 (mysql80-community)
           Necesita: libtirpc.so.3(TIRPC_0.3.0)(64bit)
Error: Paquete: mysql-community-libs-8.0.18-1.el8.x86_64 (mysql80-community)
           Necesita: libstdc++.so.6(GLIBCXX_3.4.20)(64bit)
Error: Paquete: mysql-community-server-8.0.18-1.el8.x86_64 (mysql80-community)
           Necesita: libssl.so.1.1()(64bit)
Error: Paquete: mysql-community-client-8.0.18-1.el8.x86_64 (mysql80-community)
           Necesita: libssl.so.1.1(OPENSSL_1_1_1)(64bit)
Error: Paquete: mysql-community-libs-8.0.18-1.el8.x86_64 (mysql80-community)
           Necesita: libstdc++.so.6(CXXABI_1.3.9)(64bit)
Error: Paquete: mysql-community-server-8.0.18-1.el8.x86_64 (mysql80-community)
           Necesita: libtirpc.so.3()(64bit)
Error: Paquete: mysql-community-client-8.0.18-1.el8.x86_64 (mysql80-community)
           Necesita: libssl.so.1.1()(64bit)
Error: Paquete: mysql-community-libs-8.0.18-1.el8.x86_64 (mysql80-community)
           Necesita: libcrypto.so.1.1(OPENSSL_1_1_0)(64bit)
Error: Paquete: 2:postfix-2.10.1-7.el7.x86_64 (@base)
           Necesita: libmysqlclient.so.18()(64bit)
           Eliminando: 1:mariadb-libs-5.5.64-1.el7.x86_64 (@base)
               libmysqlclient.so.18()(64bit)
           Obsoleto por: mysql-community-libs-8.0.18-1.el8.x86_64 (mysql80-community)
              ~libmysqlclient.so.21()(64bit)
Error: Paquete: mysql-community-client-8.0.18-1.el8.x86_64 (mysql80-community)
           Necesita: libncurses.so.6()(64bit)
Error: Paquete: mysql-community-libs-8.0.18-1.el8.x86_64 (mysql80-community)
           Necesita: libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.28)(64bit)
Error: Paquete: mysql-community-client-8.0.18-1.el8.x86_64 (mysql80-community)
           Necesita: libstdc++.so.6(CXXABI_1.3.9)(64bit)
Error: Paquete: mysql-community-server-8.0.18-1.el8.x86_64 (mysql80-community)
           Necesita: libstdc++.so.6(CXXABI_1.3.8)(64bit)
Error: Paquete: mysql-community-server-8.0.18-1.el8.x86_64 (mysql80-community)
           Necesita: libstdc++.so.6(CXXABI_1.3.9)(64bit)
Error: Paquete: mysql-community-client-8.0.18-1.el8.x86_64 (mysql80-community)
           Necesita: libstdc++.so.6(GLIBCXX_3.4.20)(64bit)
Error: Paquete: mysql-community-server-8.0.18-1.el8.x86_64 (mysql80-community)
           Necesita: libstdc++.so.6(GLIBCXX_3.4.22)(64bit)
Error: Paquete: mysql-community-libs-8.0.18-1.el8.x86_64 (mysql80-community)
           Necesita: libcrypto.so.1.1()(64bit)
```

Estos son los errores que me ha mandado, como le comento arriba las dependencias están instaladas, no se por que a la hora de hacer la instalación marca estos errores como si no estuvieran estas dependencias instaladas.

He instalado Mysql en otros servidores y no me había pasado esto igual con SO de Centos 7

Si alguien le ha pasado, me podría comentar como lo resolvió.

Comment: Pues, resulta que no estan instaladas. Porque dices que lo son? Como averiguaste? Quizas tienes otra version de las librerías?

Comment: De hecho quise instalarlas por aparte y cuando estaba en proceso me decía, librería ya instalada en su versión más reciente, no hay nada por hacer.

Comment: ¿Podrías especificar que repositorio estas usando para instalar MySQL 8.0 en centos7?

Comment: Revisa qué versión de esa librería está instalada. NO basta con que esté, tiene que cumplir el requisito de versión mínima que señala el error.

Answer (score 1):

yo tenía el mismo problema, intenta con agregar el argumento `--skip-broken` al final del comando de yum, a mí me funcionó con SQL Server para CentOS 7

Comment: Te invito a que leas: [answer] y [No tengo reputación para dejar un comentario, pero quiero decir algo](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/3765/107347)

Answer (score 1):

el problema puede radicar que estas instalando el MySQL para la versión 8 de CentOS, lo que estoy viendo es que estas instalando el que dice "el-8" (mysql-community-libs-8.0.18-1.**el8**.x86_64). fíjate que el archivo descargado diga **....release-el7-*....**, que este si es para CentOS 7.

Saludos.

Comment: Buen punto. Posiblemente sea eso. Repo equivocado.